# Odoo Exceptions - RedirectWarning with domain/context/filter

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13

How to give context/domain to RedirectWarning's action parameter.

```
action = self.env.ref('stock.stock_product_normal_action')
raise RedirectWarning(error_msg, action.id, _('Go to the Archived Product'))
```

This lands on product page, my aim is to land on archived product list. (Active = False)

Also if possible, in the redirected list view, have to filter out particular product/products using some domain like..

```
'domain': [('id', 'in', some_search.ids)],
```

Comment: Maybe your `stock_product_normal_action` define `fomr` first in `view_mode`, if so, define `tree` first. In other way define other `action` with only `tree` view mode.

Comment: The issue is not with form/tree. It is working fine based on action definition. 
I could not end up in tree view of Archived products(Or any archived records) no matter what domain/context we give.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your own action and view for the desired landing page with whatever domain, context, and/or filter you want. After that, you can just use the newly created action and view for the `RedirectWarning`.

Comment: could you please help me in domain/context values to pass for archived products. Where should the context be passed ?

'domain': [('active', '=', False)] did not work.